# How do I include behavior in a subclass?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport-concern

I have a concern with an `included` block. In this example it sets a class instance variable.

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Mod1
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    p "#{self}: included Mod1"
    @foo = "foo is set"
  end

  class_methods do
    def foo
      @foo
    end
  end
end
```

If I include it I get the method `foo` and the included variable is set.

```
class Parent
  include Mod1
end

p Parent.foo # "Parent: included Mod1" "foo is set"
```

But if I subclass from Parent, I *inherit* the method `foo`, but the included block is not run.

```
class Subclass < Parent
end

p Subclass.foo # nil
```

Even if I include the module, the included block is not run. I expect because `Subclass.include?(Mod1)` is true.

```
class Subclass < Parent
  include Mod1
end

p Subclass.foo # nil
p Subclass.include?(Mod1) # true
```

How do I write a concern such that its `included` block runs even on subclasses?

Answer (score 4):

[`ActiveSupport::Concern#included`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html#method-i-included) is really just syntactic sugar for [`Module#included`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Module.html#method-i-included) so it only ever fires when the module is included in the parent class. The hook you are looking for is [Class#inherited](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Class.html#method-i-inherited) which is invoked whenever a subclass of the current class is created.

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Mod1
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    set_foo!
  end

  class_methods do
    def foo
      @foo
    end

    def set_foo!
      p "Setting foo"
      @foo = "foo is set"
    end

    def inherited(child_class)
      puts "inherited!"
      child_class.set_foo!
    end
  end
end

class Parent
  include Mod1
end

class Subclass < Parent; end
```

```
require 'minitest/autorun'
class Mod1Test < Minitest::Test
  def test_class_ivar_set_in_subclass
    assert_equal("foo is set", Subclass.foo) # passes
  end
end
```

```
"Setting foo"
inherited!
"Setting foo"
Run options: --seed 35149

# Running:

.

Finished in 0.000999s, 1000.7185 runs/s, 1000.7185 assertions/s.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: This comment helped me a lot! Just a reminder to others that come across this that if you're doing this when the parent class inherits from something else (like ApplicationRecord!) to call `super(child_class)` in your parent's `inherited` method.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny here. Actually the `SubClass` has the method `foo`, but the return value `@foo` is not set. The `SubClass` inherits methods from `Parent`, but as you are using `@foo` which is a variable so it cannot be shared between 2 object `Parent` and `SubClass`.
You can check by getting the source location of the method `foo` in SubClass

```
SubClass.method(:foo).source_location
```

And if you move the logic to the method `foo`, you can see that SubClass will return the expected value.
For example:

```
require 'active_support/concern'

module Mod1
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
  end

  class_methods do
    def foo
      p "#{self}: included Mod1"
      "foo is set"
    end
  end
end
```

Then calling `foo` from `SubClass` will return `foo is set`

The `included do` in `active_support/concern` is usually used to declare Rails features such as relationships or validations or scopes.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html

Comment: This does not answer the question.  The asker is not trying to share a variable between the class and its subclass - a class variable would do that. They are trying to initialize a class instance variable in both the class and subclass.